# Line-spacing in a cell of table

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I'd like to change the line space of sentence in a cell of table. 
It is not line-breaked, but over-flowed since the sentence is quite long in the cell.

My code example is below.
The line space is quite larger than cell space, which looks so bad. 
Is there any way to make it narrow, only affecting in the cell?

Thanks in advance.

ps. Since I use \arraystretch which make cell-line small, line-space in the cell looks more bigger than cell-space.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,ctable,threeparttable}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}
    \begin{table}[t]
      \caption{Test}
      \begin{threeparttable}
         \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c l X}
                                                             \FL
           No. & Code  & Name                                \ML[0.08em]
           01  & 01XXX & Agriculture, forestry and fishing   \NN
           02  & 05XXX & Manufacture of Electronic Components, Computer, 
                         Radio, Television and Communication Equipment and Apparatuses
                                                             \NN
           03  & 06XXX & Nursing                             \LL
         \end{tabularx}
         \label{tab:test}
       \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

## Addtion.

This is how my table look. 
[image]

Comment: Please indicate how the macros `\FL`, `\ML`, `\NN`, and `\LL` are defined -- ideally by expanding your code snippet into a compilable minimum working example (MWE). By the way, for a `tabular` environment of width `\textwidth`, there's no point in specifying `\centering`.

Comment: Please be sure to indicate in your MWE *how* you've set up the change in interline space in the document -- especially if you're not using the `setspace` package and its associated commands.

Comment: @Mico \FL is from Ctable package. and you are right on the comment for no \centering. thanks.

Comment: It looks like one of your objectives (or constraints?) is to cram as many lines as possible into a given table (e.g., to make it fit on one page). If so, I think you're better off reducing the font size used in the table, e.g., by issuing the command `\small` or `\footnotesize` after `\begin{table}`. Doing so is more likely to succeed in preserving some overall balance between text size and interline distance.

Comment: @Mico I put a picture on my question. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\arraystretch` only affects line spacing between table rows.  In an `X` column, you can change the spacing between lines inside a cell by adjusting `\baselineskip`.  Below is the same example coded in two slightly different ways, the first using `\ctable`, the other using your `tabularx` set-up.  Notice the `\ctable` gives better spacing for the caption relative to the table.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\ctable[caption = Test,pos=htp,width=\textwidth]
{c l >{\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip}}X}{}{
\FL
No. & Code  & Name                                \ML[0.08em]
01  & 01XXX & Agriculture, forestry and fishing   \NN
02  & 05XXX & Manufacture of Electronic Components, Computer, 
Radio, Television and Communication Equipment and Apparatuses
\NN
03  & 06XXX & Nursing                             \LL
}}

\begin{table}[htp]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \caption{Test}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c l >{\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip}}X}
    \FL
    No. & Code  & Name                                \ML[0.08em]
    01  & 01XXX & Agriculture, forestry and fishing   \NN
    02  & 05XXX & Manufacture of Electronic Components, Computer, 
    Radio, Television and Communication Equipment and Apparatuses
    \NN
    03  & 06XXX & Nursing                             \LL
  \end{tabularx}
  \label{tab:test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I demonstrated this with increasing the spacing, as this is more realistic.  Squeezing will work too, just replace both `1.5` by `0.75` in the `\arraystretch` and the `>{...}X`, but it does not look too good.  As Mico suggests, in such situations reducing font sizes is better.
In both cases, note that the change to `\arraystretch` has been inside a group/environment, to prevent this affecting other places later in the document.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer. it works and looks good.
One more asking additionally, i was using \small for each cell of name such as \small Agriculture, .... \small Manufature of ..., leaving top row as normal font. 
With \small, \baselineskip doesn't work. Can you figure it out? and any solution for small size font only for table contents, not top(head) row?

Comment: @Kens_kr - Rather than issuing lots of `\small` directives in individual cells, you may want to (i) issue a single `\small` directive  before the start of the `\ctable` environment and (ii) restore the "normal" font size for just the limited number of cells in the header row by issuing `\normalsize` statements at the starts of those cells.

Answer (score 4):

To reduce line spacing, try:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
```