# How do I create parallel columns that automatically adjust line spacing

Tags: vertical-alignment, parallel

Let's say I have some text that I have in multiple languages and want to display in parallel, as shown below. **This text might span multiple pages.**

[image: Example]

How can I make it so that the line height on the shorter texts is automatically adjusted to make it take up the same amount of space as the longest text, as shown above?

EDIT: Here's an [example using Malipivo's approach](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/55086872c42f8dfd35e239b9) which is close to what I want except that it does not deal with page-breaking for text that spans multiple pages. The text wrapping is also a bit ugly, but I can probably manage to finagle around that issue.

Comment: Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help. Hints like **I do (not) like multicol** or **It need (not) to deal with page-breaking** are also helpful.

Comment: Maybe you can get some inspiration in the solution given by egreg in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147545/how-do-i-ask-latex-to-exactly-fill-up-a-page, and perhaps this might be also of help http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128615/line-spacing-in-a-cell-of-table

Comment: In a vertical group you could use `\baselineskip=12pt plus 1fill`.

Comment: @Symbol1 I did mention multiple pages in the question, but I guess it wasn't obvious, so I've emphasized it now. I don't care especially what library is used (multicol, parcolumns, etc.) as long as it works.

Comment: paracol and eledpar are both used for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution introduces the `\langs{text1}{text2}{text3}` macro with desired output. The implementation calculates the coefficients for all three columns and uses `\vsplit` with these coefficients if the text spans multiple pages.

Of course, my solution is in plain TeX but if you need to use it in another formats, I believe that this will be no problem.

```
\newdimen\colhsize
\newcount\tmpnum \newdimen\tmpdim
\newdimen\pagesize \newdimen \maxht \newdimen\coef
\newif\ifrepeat

{\lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t  \lowercase{\gdef\ignorept#1?!{#1}}}

\def\langs#1#2#3{\setbox1=\vbox{\setbaselines #1}\setbox0=\vsplit1 to0pt
   \setbox2=\vbox{\setbaselines #2}\setbox0=\vsplit2 to0pt
   \setbox3=\vbox{\setbaselines #3}\setbox0=\vsplit3 to0pt \printlangs
}
\def\setbaselines{\penalty0
   \advance\baselineskip by 0pt plus1em \relax
   \advance\hsize by-4em \divide\hsize by3
}
\def\printlangs{\par \repeattrue 
   \loop \maxht=\ht1
      \ifdim\maxht<\ht2 \maxht=\ht2 \fi  \ifdim\maxht<\ht3 \maxht=\ht3 \fi
      \pagesize=\pagegoal
      \ifdim\pagesize=\maxdimen \pagesize=\vsize
      \else \advance\pagesize by-\baselineskip \fi
      \advance\pagesize by-\pagetotal
      \ifdim\maxht>\pagesize
         \tmpnum=\maxht \divide\tmpnum by256 
         \splitlang1 \splitlang2 \splitlang3   
         \putlangboxes\pagesize{11}{12}{13}\vfil\break
      \else \putlangboxes\maxht123 \repeatfalse \fi
   \ifrepeat \repeat
}
\def\splitlang#1 {\coef=\ht#1 \divide\coef by\tmpnum \multiply\coef by256
   \tmpdim=\pagesize 
   \ifdim\ht#1=\maxht \else \advance\tmpdim by-\baselineskip \fi
   \setbox 1#1=\vsplit #1 to \expandafter\ignorept\the\coef \tmpdim
}
\def\putlangboxes#1#2#3#4{\hbox{\vbox to#1{\unvbox#2}\kern2em
   \vbox to#1{\unvbox#3}\kern2em \vbox to#1{\unvbox#4}}}

%%% The test:

\def\text{Rr eiewb ei s sd fuz dhg fg zd jd ffj  xds c sg xv fxdz xvv zhx cdfg.}
\def\textA{\text\par\text\text\par\text}
\def\textB{\text\text\text\par\text\text\par\text\text} 
\def\textC{\text\text\par\text\text\text}

This text is before language columns. \text\text

\langs{Language one: \textA\textA\textA\textA\textA\textA\textA\textA}
      {Language two: \textB\textB\textB\textB\textB\textB\textB\textB}
      {Language three: \textC\textC\textC\textC\textC\textC\textC\textC} 

This text follows. \text\text

\bye
```

Explanation of implementation details. The `text1` is set to box1 as `\vbox` with `\baselineskip=\baselineskip plus\vsize`. This makes potential stretching of `\baselineskip`. The `text2` is set to box2 and `text3` to box3 similarly. The first element of all boxes are `\penalty0`. The first `\vsplit` to all three boxes is applied at this `\penalty0` in order to set the `\splittopskip` above the first line in all boxes. This ensures that the first line will be at the same position in all three boxes when we will do `\vbox to something{\unvbox1}` etc.

The `\printlangs` macro measures the space on the page `\pagesize` and does the loop of splitting texts. The `\maxht` is maximal height of the boxes. If `\maxht>\pagesize` then we need to split the boxes and repeat the loop. Else we need to print the boxes and end the loop. The macro `\splitlang` does the `\vsplit` of the given box to the given size `\pagesize` multiplied by coeeficient `\ht-of current box` over `\maxht`. The result of the splitting is stored from box1 to box11, from box2 to box12, from box3 to box13.
The macro `\putlangboxes` prints `\hbox{\vbox{}\vbox{}\vbox{}}`, i.e the three columns and does reboxing all given boxes to the size given in `#1`.

Edid: I have had a bug in the `\setbaselines`: `\advance\baselineskip by 0pt plus\vsize`. The `\vsize` value was incremented per each line and as the result the value was overfull at line 49 and next lines have had negative `plus` value. Solution: I write `plus1em`. This value will never overfull. Another solution: write `plus1fil`.

Comment: I do have a question about how to adjust the vertical margins. [Here's an example of some weird spacing, especially on the last page, if I change the top margin to 2cm](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/550b3602a6e9fe3a13cf8ed8), but if the margin is left as default, it seems to work normally.

Comment: @PeterOlson Do you mean the sparse columns at the last page? Maybe there i a bug in my code. Try to replace the line `\advance\baselineskip by 0pt plus\vsize \relax` by the line `\advance\baselineskip by 0pt plus1fil \relax`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I dont understand it correctly but one suggestion is the following MWE. I compiled via pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

% http://uucode.com/blog/2010/12/06/multi-page-tables-with-inter-row-page-breaks/
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\showboxbreadth=100
\showboxdepth=100


\makeatletter
\let\oldDispatch=\cals@row@dispatch
\newbox\rowBefore
\newbox\rowAfter
\newbox\decorationCopy
\newdimen\splitHeight

\def\cals@row@dispatch{%
\cals@ifbreak\iftrue % detect that a break is required
  \splitHeight=\pagegoal \advance\splitHeight -\pagetotal
  \ifdim \splitHeight>50pt % break inrow only if at least 100pt left
    \advance\splitHeight -5pt % avoid pagebreak due to overflows
    %
    % Split the current row on two: before and after the break
    %
    \setbox\rowBefore=\hbox{}
    \setbox\rowAfter=\hbox{}
    \def\next{%
      \setbox0=\lastbox
      \ifvoid0
        \def\next{\global\setbox\rowBefore=\box\rowBefore
                  \global\setbox\rowAfter=\box\rowAfter }%
      \else
        \setbox2=\vsplit0 to\splitHeight
        \setbox\rowBefore=\hbox{\box2 \unhbox\rowBefore}%
        \setbox\rowAfter=\hbox{\box0 \unhbox\rowAfter}%
      \fi
      \next}
    \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox\cals@current@row \next}
    %
    % Decoration backup, typeset the first row,
    % restore context, typeset the second at the end of macro
    %
    \setbox\decorationCopy=\copy\cals@current@cs
    \setbox\cals@current@row=\box\rowBefore
    \ht\cals@current@cs=\ht\cals@current@row
    \oldDispatch
    \cals@issue@break
    \cals@thead@tokens
    \setbox\cals@current@row=\box\rowAfter
    \cals@reheight@cells\cals@current@row
    \setbox\cals@current@cs=\box\decorationCopy
    \ht\cals@current@cs=\ht\cals@current@row
    \let\cals@current@context=b
  \fi
\fi
\oldDispatch}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\cals@rs@width{0pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}
\def\cals@rs@color{red}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{150pt}{150pt}{150pt}}
% \thead{\brow \bfseries \cell{header1}\cell{header2}\cell{header3}
  % \mdseries \erow}
\brow \cell{\lipsum[ 1]}\cell{\lipsum[ 2]}\cell{\lipsum[ 3]} \erow
\brow \cell{\lipsum[16]}\cell{\lipsum[17]}\cell{\lipsum[18]} \erow
\end{calstable}

\end{document}
```

The most part is used from  http://uucode.com/blog/2010/12/06/multi-page-tables-with-inter-row-page-breaks/

I have reset the linewidth to zero in order to prevent black lines. Also I have removed the header, so pagebreaks can go along cells. You have to input your text in one cell of each column.

Best regards

Peter Ebelserger

Comment: This seems to work fine for making the parallel cells that go over a page break, but as far as I can tell, the line height is not adjusted to make the text in parallel cells take up the same vertical space. (See picture example in question to see what I mean)

Comment: Now I understand. But my example solves another problem. ;)